# How can I check if javascript is enabled and factor that into the web page?

Tags: javascript, forms, button, anchor

I want to use a button to submit a form if the person is not using JavaScript and use a anchor tag to submit a form if the person is using JavaScript. How would I do this?

Comment: Look at the <noscript> tag for a start

Answer (score 5):

I suggest building the page in plain HTML only. Then with JavaScript, replace those elements with the JavaScript enabled version. In your case, build your form with the submit button. Then using JavaScript, replace that submit button with a link.

If you haven't come across this method, it's called [*Progressive Enhancement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) which, in summary, is developing a product with full working functionality at its very basic (in your case, the submit button) and add in the optional parts (the link, using JS).

Answer (score 1):

The initial HTML should only include the button, but have your javascript remove the button and replace it with an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Display the button inside `<noscript>` tags by default.  Also by default, set the CSS of the anchor to `display: none;`.  In the page load event, use JavaScript to display your anchor.  If JS is not enabled, this will not occur and the button will be displayed only.

```
    <a href="#" style="display: none;" id="JsVersion">click me</a>

    <noscript><input type="button" id="NoJsVersion" value="click me" /></noscript>

    <script>
    //Assuming you are using jQuery
    $("document").ready(
       function(){
          $("#JsVersion").show();
       }        
    );
    </script>
```

Comment: Joseph's answer really is better as he is telling you about the overall use of progressive enhancement.  I will leave my answer up purely so that you can grab a working code example.

Comment: Also do not assume jQuery. If this was the only enhancement, then jQuery would be massive overkill for something that could be handled with documen.write or innerHTML

Comment: @mplungjan--Fair enough.  TO THE OP:  I don't have time to edit my answer right now, but mplunjan makes a good point.